# Can you explain how the memory is used under multi-threaded java program?

Tags: java

Consider a multi-threaded java program with 10 threads. Its heap size is set to 128M max. When the application is executed, in windows / Linux, it’s showing usage of 160 MB. Can you explain how the memory is used ?

Comment: You should use VisualVM tool to assess the memory behavior of your program.

Comment: There's more memory being used than just the heap, likely.

Comment: What if I told you that the heap memory you set is not all the memory the process uses?

Comment: Memory that is not used for the heap or for the code/data segments is used for thread stacks.

Comment: Besides, is there any java program that isn't multi-threaded?  I vaguely remember coding for a smartcard VM that didn't have a [finalizer thread](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2010/01/garbage-collection-references.html) since it was used in severely constrained environments but that was years ago.

Comment: What the others said.  You've got Java object heap, a stack for each thread (actually, two stacks for each Java thread, and a stack each for, eg, garbage collector threads), a C-language heap separate from the Java heap, and, depending on what value you look at, storage for the JVM code itself.

Answer (score 0):

The max heap size of a process is only the amount of memory it can allocate to global variables etc. The heap can not exceed this limit, but there are other parts of the process that will get additional memory from the OS.

Every single thread will have it's own stack allocated (often 4 or 8 KB per thread but that can also be tweaked) where all local variables, method parameters and return addresses are pushed and pulled over the lifetime of the thread.

In addition the JVM garbage collector will also be given a certain amount of memory to deal with the chaos left in your program's wake.

You can read more about JVM tweaking and what is does [here](http://crunchify.com/jvm-tuning-heapsize-stacksize-garbage-collection-fundamental/).